# axis.break does not move with axis R

Tags: r, plot, axis, plotrix

I want to plot the vector `4:10` but from 0 to 10. I don't like the large gap in produces, and I want to create my own style of plot, so I write the code:

```
plot(4:10,axes=FALSE,ylim=c(2,10),xlim=c(0,8))
axis(1,pos=2)
axis(2,pos=0,at=seq(2,10,2),labels=c('0','4','6','8','10'))
```

In order to not mislead the audience, I want to put in an axis break using `axis.break()` from `plotrix`. Unfortunately, when I add

```
axis.break(2,2.5)
```

on my plot, I don't get the break where my axis is but where it would be if I used the default axis. How do I get `axisbreak()` to move with my axis? Or else, how do I put an axis break where I want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `pos=0` to your `axis.break`:

```
plot(4:10,axes=FALSE,ylim=c(2,10),xlim=c(0,8))
axis(1,pos=2)
axis(2,pos=0,at=seq(2,10,2),labels=c('0','4','6','8','10'))
axis.break(2,2.5,pos=0)
```

[image]

Comment: I wish the would have the have at least the `...` in the documentation -_-